# conversion from string yyyyMMdd to type integer is not valid

Tags: vb.net, datetime, format, tostring

I have a dataset containing a datatable, and I enumerate all rows in that datatable. When trying to format a column in that row, I run into an exception. (Part of) the code is:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables("records").Rows
    file = dr("timestamp").ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "~.wav"
Next
```

This results in the following error message:

**Conversion from string yyyyMMdd to type Integer is not valid.**
(translated from a Dutch error message to the English equivalent)

dr("timestamp").GetType.FullName results in "System.DateTime", so I don't understand why I run into this exception, as for example **Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")** results in "20091002", and "Now" is of the same type as dr("timestamp"), "System.DateTime" that is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables("records").Rows
    file = CDate(dr("timestamp")).ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "~.wav"
Next
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks a lot for helping me out. Unfortunately I cannot mod your answer up, as I do not seem to have the required credits for that :(

Comment: Well, he got a +1 from me ;)  Also you can set his answer as "accepted" by clicking the green "v" (checkmark) below the up/downvote number.

Comment: Although this checkmark is pretty big, I didn't notice it ;)
Answer is now accepted though.

Comment: This also seems to be necessary with SqlDataReader returns.  I wonder if it has to do with some interaction between .tostring and the implicit conversion from object to date?

Comment: Commenting on old post because I ran into a variant of this problem - a nullable DateTime (DateTime?) also needs to be explicitly cast in order to use ToString (it is not automatically recognized as a Date/DateTime, hence the cast). I was not expecting that!

Comment: My mistake was *CDate(dr("timestamp").ToString("yyyyMMdd"))*.  Note that my ToString is *inside* of the convert.  I just needed to do the formatring after the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this issue too, although in my case the value in question was a **nullable** Date/DateTime.

As well as casting to a Date, as another answer has suggested, you can also call `.Value` to get a non-nullable value (after making sure it isn't actually null, of course).

Answer (score -1):

Have you made sure that you are not declaring the variable 'file' as an integer?

Comment: file was declared as string, but thanks for helping me anyway.