# SSRS - expression warning for date time format

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I need to grab the Month and Year info from 2 date/time parameters of my report (Start date and End date) into a textbox.

I used the following expression -

```
=MonthName(Month(Parameters!StartDate.Value)) & Format(Year(Parameters!EndDate.Value)) & " to " & MonthName(Month(Parameters!EndDate.Value)) & Format(Year(Parameters!EndDate.Value))
```

to get it into something like e.g. March 2012 to August 2012.

It works, however I keep getting the following Warning:

```
[rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox18.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Conversion from type 'Date' to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, see this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1508591/763029 for the general workaround idea

Answer (score 1):

Is that the exact expression you are using? It doesn't seem like it is because:

- that expression works without warnings (on my system)
- it doesn't give the output that you indicate it does
- the expression is wrong (it lists the year of the EndDate twice rather than the StartDate's year with the StartDate's month)

So I would guess that one of the functions in the actual expression is `MonthName(Parameters!StartDate.Value)` rather than `MonthName(Month(Parameters!StartDate.Value))` which would give the error indicated.

This also works:

```
=MonthName(Month(Parameters!StartDate.Value)) & " " & Year(Parameters!StartDate.Value).ToString() & " to " & MonthName(Month(Parameters!EndDate.Value)) & " " & Year(Parameters!EndDate.Value).ToString()
```

Either that or this isn't the expression in `Textbox18`

Comment: Thanks so much Chris. Yea you're right with 3rd point, I made the mistake and using EndDate twice. But that shouldn't be causing the warning! I'll give your solution a go. Thank you very much!